# Android Execption ViewHolder cannot be cast to another Viewholder

Tags: android

I try to use my FriendList Adapter on my listview,but when I try to slide the list, it comes out a exception:

> 10-02 22:55:54.503 25872-25872/com.snapchat.team2.snapchat
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                *Process: com.snapchat.team2.snapchat, PID: 25872
>                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter.ChatFriendListAdapter$ViewHolder1
>   cannot be cast to
>   com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter.ChatFriendListAdapter$ViewHolder2
>                                                                                    at
>   com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter.ChatFriendListAdapter.getView(ChatFriendListAdapter.java:82)*

**These are my codes**

```
package com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.ListAdapterDataModel.Friend;
import com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class ChatFriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<Friend> ls;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final int ITEM_TYPE_1=1;
private final int ITEM_TYPE_2=2;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ls.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ls.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Friend item = ls.get(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    ViewHolder1 holder1 = null;
    ViewHolder2 holder2 = null;

    if(convertView ==null){
        switch (type){
            case ITEM_TYPE_1:
                holder1 = new ViewHolder1();
                convertView = inflater .inflate(R.layout.chat_friend_list_item,null);
                holder1.t_initial_1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_letter);
                holder1.t_name_1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_name);
                holder1.t_initial_1.setText(item.getInitial_letter());
                holder1.t_name_1.setText(item.getName());
                convertView.setTag(holder1);
                break;
            case ITEM_TYPE_2:
                holder2 = new ViewHolder2();
                convertView = inflater.inflate((R.layout.chat_frind_list_item_2),null);
                holder2.t_name_2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_name_2);
                holder2.t_name_2.setText(item.getName());
                convertView.setTag(holder2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        switch (type){
            case ITEM_TYPE_1:
                holder1 = (ViewHolder1)convertView.getTag();
                holder1.t_initial_1.setText(item.getInitial_letter());
                holder1.t_name_1.setText(item.getName());
                break;
            case ITEM_TYPE_2:
                holder2 = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
                holder2.t_name_2.setText(item.getName());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return  convertView;


}

public int getItemViewType(int position){
    return ls.get(position).getItem_type();
}

//constructor
public ChatFriendListAdapter(Context context,List<Friend> list){
    this.ls=list;
    //this.inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


class ViewHolder1{
    TextView t_initial_1;
    TextView t_name_1;
}
class ViewHolder2{
    TextView t_name_2;
}

}
```

Why this will happen. It is a problem of the Layout inflater?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `ViewHolder` like this.

```
public class ViewHolder1 extends ViewHolder {

    private final TextView t_initial_1;
    private final TextView t_name_1;

    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Find the views here
        t_initial_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t_initial_1);
        t_name_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t_name_1);
    }
}
```

Do the same thing for `ViewHolder2`

Comment: I did that , but of no use, the exception is from this line:        
             holder2 = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag();

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter.ChatFriendListAdapter$ViewHolder1 cannot be cast to com.snapchat.team2.snapchat.customAdapter.ChatFriendListAdapter$ViewHolder2

Comment: I fix that, the method is that ,in the method getView I let covertView=null, so that it won't invoke the else part and it works. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are more options with a listview in a Activity, if you clicked the one option and length of listview is greater than the length of screen, after you clicked the other option will wrong. because now the convertview is not null but the holder is null,you can do it:

```
    switch(type){
        case ITEM_TYPE_1:
            if (holder1 == null) {
                holder1 = new ViewHolder1();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_friend_list_item, null);
                holder1.t_initial_1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_letter);
                holder1.t_name_1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_name);
                holder1.t_initial_1.setText(item.getInitial_letter());
                holder1.t_name_1.setText(item.getName());
                convertView.setTag(holder1);
            } else {
                holder1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
            }
            break;
        case ITEM_TYPE_2:
            if (holder2 == null) {
                holder2 = new ViewHolder2();
                convertView = inflater.inflate((R.layout.chat_frind_list_item_2), null);
                holder2.t_name_2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_friend_name_2);
                holder2.t_name_2.setText(item.getName());
                convertView.setTag(holder2);
            } else {
                holder2 = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag();
            }
            break;
    }
```